# library database

Tags: sql, oracle

In my database
I have five tables: `books`, `magazines`, `customer`, `reservation`, `items_brrwd`. If anyone borrows a book, the data is stored in `item_brrwd` table. How can I get the most borrowed book?

I need your help pls.

Here is my database.

Books.

```
 CREATE TABLE "M_5126582"."BOOKS" 
   (    "B_ID" NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "TITLE" VARCHAR2(45 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "AUTHOR" VARCHAR2(45 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "PUBLISHER" VARCHAR2(45 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "YEAR" DATE NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "GENRE" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "NOPAGES" NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "BOOKS_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("B_ID")
);
```

items_brrwd.

```
CREATE TABLE "M_5126582"."ITEM_BRRWD" 
(   "ITEMBORROWED_ID" NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"CUSTOMER_ID" NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"BOOK_ID" NUMBER(*,0), 
"NUM_BOOK" NUMBER(*,0), 
"MAGAZINE_ID" NUMBER(*,0), 
"NUM_MAGAZINES" NUMBER(*,0), 
"BRRWD_DATE" DATE, 
"RETURN_DATE" DATE, 
"EBOOK_DOWNLOAD_DATE" DATE, 
 CONSTRAINT "ITEM_BRRWD_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ITEMBORROWED_ID")
);
```

customer.

```
CREATE TABLE "M_5126582"."CUSTOMER" 
(   "CUSTOMERID" NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"NAME" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"ADDRESS" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"ITEMNOBRRWD" NUMBER(*,0), 
"REGISTRATIONDATE" DATE NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"NUM_BOOKS" NUMBER(*,0), 
"NUM_MAGAZINES" NUMBER(*,0), 
 CONSTRAINT "CUSTOMER_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("CUSTOMERID")) ;
```

magazines.

```
CREATE TABLE "M_5126582"."MAGAZINES" 
(   "M_ID" NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"TITLE" VARCHAR2(45 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"ISSUEDATE" DATE NOT NULL ENABLE, 
 CONSTRAINT "MAGAZINES_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("M_ID")
);
```

reservation.

```
CREATE TABLE "M_5126582"."RESERVATION" 
(   "CUSTOMERID" NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"ITEMID" NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"NOINTHEQUEUE" NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
 CONSTRAINT "RESERVATION_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("CUSTOMERID")
);
```

Comment: I won't answer directly, but will try to guide you. You can `SELECT` the `COUNT` of all `Itme_Brrwd`. If you include then `GROUP BY` the `B_ID` you will see how many times each B_ID has been borrowed. If you then `JOIN` this to the `BOOK` table you can get the `TITLE` for each `B_ID` to include in your `COUNT` query, not forgetting to `GROUP BY` the `TITLE`.

Comment: thanks. ill be on it now and hit you with the result

Comment: select count(*) from item_brrwd group by book_id join books on books.title = item_brrwd.book_id group by book.title; this is the code i generated from your explaination doesnt seems to work but the first part about showing how many time each b_id was borrowed worked.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested it, but this might work.
This would find the most borrowed book title.

```
SELECT
 bk.TITLE, 
 COUNT(*) AS TotalBorrowed
FROM M_5126582.ITEM_BRRWD brrwd
JOIN M_5126582.BOOKS bk ON bk.B_ID = brrwd.BOOK_ID
GROUP BY bk.TITLE
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
```

Or the old style TOP n

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
  SELECT bk.TITLE, 
  COUNT(*) AS TotalBorrowed
  FROM M_5126582.ITEM_BRRWD brrwd
  JOIN M_5126582.BOOKS bk ON bk.B_ID = brrwd.BOOK_ID
  GROUP BY bk.TITLE
  ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
) q
WHERE ROWNUM <= 1
```

Comment: thanks for trying but this is the reply i get ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 37 Column: 27

Comment: The FETCH is something in Oracle 12c onward. Are you using 11g?

Comment: yes it did @lukstorms thank you so much. can you explain if you dont mind?

Comment: ROWNUM isn't a real column. It's a value that tells the order in which a record was returned from the Sql. So the first returned record by DESCending Count has ROWNUM 1.  Also explained [here](https://renenyffenegger.ch/notes/development/databases/Oracle/SQL/select/first-n-rows/) and [here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/top-n-queries)